# How to generate an xml hierarchy with Untangle

Tags: python, xml, tree, hierarchy

I am trying to parse an XML file using the [Untangle library](https://untangle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#).

I need to generate a tree (hierarchy) from the XML file like this:

```
root.countries.country[1].AnimalShop[1].Name = "DogShop"
root.countries.country[1].AnimalShop[2].Name = "CatShop"
root.countries.country[1].AnimalShop[3].Name = "CowShop"
root.countries.country[1].SeaShop[2].Name = "SharkShop"
root.countries.country[1].SeaShop[2].Address = "1 road of stockoverflow"
```

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what you mean by "a tree" here - that looks like a list of the elements. Are you wanting to iterate over all the elements it creates and show what their contents are?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/stchris/untangle/blob/master/untangle.py, that shows you what methods you can call on `root`. You can get at the elements in each successive elements by iterating through their `children` attribute (this is a list of all the child elements), and checking for whether they have any text by checking their `cdata` attribute.

Comment: @bouteillebleu Yes exactly, i'm French, i have some difficulty in English aha ! So yes i want to iterate over al the elements and creates and show what their contents ! But how are modify me title ? It's not really that ! I want to create an hierarchy but not absolutly with Untangle !

Answer (score 1):

```
import untangle
    obj = untangle.parse("D:/.....xml")
#use "children" it's predeveloped
    mainmodel = obj.GrandFather.children
    for element in mainmodel:
      model =element.children
      for ele in model:
        print(ele._name)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add some explanation to your code.